# combining multiple variables into another variable in unix

Tags: unix, variables

My question says it all: I am trying to combining multiple variables into another variable in unix

```
VAR1=abc
VAR2=def
VA3=ghi
VAR4=$VAR1 $VAR2 $VAR3
echo $VAR4
#expected output:
abcdefghi
```

Comment: `for buyerserverArg in $WS102JOBNODES $WS102USERNODES $WS102CATALOGADMINNODE $WS102CATALOGSEARCHNODES $WS102SMTPNODES $WS102PRI
     do`

can i do something like this in for loop?

Answer (score 1):

```
 echo "${VAR1}${VAR2}${VAR3}"
```

Will do it.

Assigning works the same way:

```
 VAR4="${VAR1}${VAR2}${VAR3}"
```

HTH

Answer (score 0):

VAR4="${VAR1}${VAR2}${VA3}"

(You've spelt `VAR3`as `VA3`).